# JQuery Multiple Choice Multiple Feedback If Statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, multiple-choice

I'm trying to create a multiple feedback jquery question I need a little help with my if-statement code.  I have one correct answer but would like to have a different feedback alert for selecting each wrong answer. I would like it to give a different feed back for each wrong answer. For example, "You selected grey, there is a better answer, please select again." or "you selected black, there is a better answer."

Here is my code so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/nhxuy/

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    //variable of correct answers   
    var rules = ['correct'];

    //force checkboxes to work like radio buttons
    var boxes = $("input[name=q4]:checkbox").click(function () {
        boxes.not(this).attr('checked', false);
    });



    $('.submit4').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //check correct answers from var above
        if ($('input[name=q4]:checked').map(function (i, v) {
            return v.id;
        }).get().join(',') == rules[0]) {
            alert("Correct! Reflective colors should make you more visible at night");

        } else {

            $('.grey:checked').attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeAttr('checked');
            alert("grey is wrong... it might not be bright enough.");
        }



    });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <h1> Question  </h1>

<p>What is the best color to wear after dark?</p>
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q4" class="grey"></input>grey</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q4" class="black"></input>black</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q4" class="white"></input>white</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q4" class="red"></input>red</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q4" id="correct"></input>reflective yellow</label>
    <br />
    <button class="submit4">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: '`//force checkboxes to work like radio buttons`' why not use radio buttons?!

Comment: It's purely cosmetic... To match all the other multiple choice questions which have multiple answers and handled differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I suggest you use a `switch`, something like (just implement your own logic):

```
$('.submit4').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //check correct answers from var above
    var result;
    switch($('input[name=q4]:checked').attr('class')){
        case 'grey': 
            result = "it's grey";
            break;
        case 'black':
            result = "it's black";
            break;
        case 'white':
            result = "it's white";
            break;
        case 'red':
            result = "it's red";
            break;
        default:
            result = 'Correct answer!';
            break;
    }
    alert(result);

});
```

In this case the switch works by getting the class of the selected checkbox, and you can do whatever you want on each case instead of using a bunch of if/elses...

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/q4rJ8/

Comment: Thanks darkajax! This works great. Much simpler and better solution!